# What is the recommended way to include a standard header/footer on a static html website?

Tags: html, apache, web, server-side-includes

I have a website (Apache) that is all static html and I want to include certain content across all pages, for example a footer.  Are good 'ol server side includes (SSI) still the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will be the simplest solution in this case, just follow the security tips for SSI at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use SSI's anymore, they are vulnerable to security leaks. It's also a lot easier to just include static HTML with whatever servers side language you're using (PHP, Node.JS, JSP, or whatever), as they allow for a lot more extensibility

Because that would break some links, you could use this in your `.htaccess` to redirect those links

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: I am 100% .html files today but given that I am on Apache I could go the php route and then use php's include() command.  This means that (a) I will be creating php files for all my content rather than .html files and then (b) have to somehow not break my existing links, either by url rewrites or setting permanent redirects on the .html files.  Am I correct about (a) and (b)?

Comment: You could just rename your files with the `include()`s, but not the static HTML

Comment: Agree, to minimize my work.  But for the ones that I do have to make .php, am I correct in my two assumptions (a) and (b)?

Comment: SSI is no more of a security risk than php for static HTML files.

Comment: Just follow the security tips for SSI on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html

Comment: @scrblnrd3 - If my original page is mypage.html and I change that into a mypage.php page so I can do the php include() statement, I would break existing links to the mypage.html unless I did a redirect or some other rewrite, no?

Comment: You can have php parse .html files too. If you have access to apache settings.http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm